# JQuery never reaches success or fail on aspx returning json

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

Basicaly I have my aspx page doing

```
<%
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Write("{\"Success\": \"true\" }");
        Response.End();
%>
```

My JQuery code is

```
function DoSubmit(r) {
    if (r == null || r.length == 0 || formdata == null || formdata.length == 0) return;
    for (i = 0; i < formdata.length; i++)
    {
        var fd = formdata[i];
        r[fd.Name] = fd.Value;
    }
    r["ModSeq"] = tblDef.ModSeq;
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "NashcoUpdate.aspx"
        , succsess: doRow
        , error: DoSubmitError
        , complete: DoSubmitComplete
        , dataType: "json"
        , cache: false
        , data: r
        , type: "post"
    })
}
```

When I call the DoSubmit() function every thing works but the doRow or DoSubmitError functions never get called only the DoSubmitComplete function.

When I look at the response text in teh DoSubmitComple function it is

```
{"Success": "true" }
```

Every JSON tester I have tried says that this is valied JSON.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you paste the full code (ie the doRow and doSubmitError) functions.

Wouldnt be the fact you've spelt success wrong (succsess)?

Comment: DOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOH.


Please add your misspelling as an answer and I will mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misspelled "success" as "succsess" ;)